# Can "it is" be discarded here?

Tags: sentence-construction

> the “scrap grubbers” who make the waste industry far more industrious than **it is** wasteful.

Can *it is* be discarded here?

If yes, will this make the sentence less natural or counter to normal usage?

Source:[LARB](http://lareviewofbooks.org/review/the-afterlives-of-discarded-objects-adam-minters-junkyard-planet)

Comment: I think there's a slight nuance to including **it is** there. Without it, the intended meaning may simply be that *industrious* describes the waste industry better than *wasteful* (which doesn't necessarily imply that the industry is at all "wasteful"). When **it is** is included, there's a clear implication that the industry *is to some extent "wasteful"* (but its industriousness outweighs its wastefulness).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I need to point out that this isn't a sentence. Drop the "who" to make the sentence about the "scrap grubbers." Keeping the who means this is all, essentially, the subject of the sentence.

But, yes, you can drop "it is" without any change in meaning. If you drop the "who" to make this a sentence, "it is" fits equally well as simply dropping dropping "it is". On the other hand, if you keep this as a sentence fragment and add on a predicate, the "it is" sounds a little awkward to me but it's still understandable.

In the first case, I think they are equally natural and up to preference. In the second case, I think "it is" is a bit awkward. I think it's because of the verbs. In the first case, the implication seems to be that the scrap grubbers preclude wastefulness in the industry so you wouldn't say "it is wasteful". In the second case, it seems more like a defensive statement where you're not necessarily denying the wastefulness.